# Laravel Eloquent - Polymorphic Relationships With Two ID Columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following columns in my **games** table:

```
-match_type
-team_one_id
-team_two_id
```

The *match_type* column can have either a value of **singles** or **doubles**.  I have two additional tables called **users** and **pairs**.

If the value of *match_type* is **singles**, I would like the *team_one_id* and *team_two_id* columns to relate to the **users** table.  If the value of *match_type* is **doubles**,  I would like the two columns to relate to the **pairs** table.

How would I do this with Eloquent - where the relationships for two columns depend on the value of a type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to overwrite the `morphMany()` method from Laravel's **Model** class to allow for custom column names to be used for the polymorphic relationships.  By default, Laravel uses *_type* and *_id* suffixes to identify columns it needs for polymoprhic relationships.  These two columns also have to have the same prefixes (ie. ***reference***_type and ***reference***_id).

In my **User** and **Pair** models, I have the following:

```
// Overwrite morphMany() so we can use custom columns
public function morphMany($related, $name, $type = null, $id = null, $localKey = null){

    $instance = new $related;
    $table = $instance->getTable();
    $localKey = $localKey ? : $this->getKeyName();
    return new MorphMany($instance->newQuery(), $this, $table . '.' . $type, $table . '.' . $id, $localKey);

}
```

This allows me to establish relationships with the *Games* table using:

```
// Defines the relationship between this table and the games table through the team_one_id column
public function game_team_one(){

    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Game', null, 'match_type', 'team_one_id');

}

// Defines the relationship between this table and the games table through the team_two_id column
public function game_team_two(){

    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Game', null, 'match_type', 'team_two_id');

}
```

Then, in the **Game** model, you would use `morphTo()` with the first three optional parameters filled in (to overwrite the default column names) to establish our polymorphic relationships:

```
// Defines the relationship between this table and the users / pairs table through the team_one_id column
public function team_one(){

    return $this->morphTo(null, 'match_type', 'team_one_id');

}

// Defines the relationship between this table and the users / pairs table through the team_two_id column
public function team_two(){

    return $this->morphTo(null, 'match_type', 'team_two_id');

}
```